# Crop and resize image with Image Magician

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm using Image Magician to crop and resize images to exact size - 230 x 300px.
About 90 % of images are resized and croped to exact size, but some of them not.

My code :

```
$magicianObj = new \Application\Model\ImageMagician($imageLocation);   
$magicianObj -> resizeImage(230, 300, 'crop');
$magicianObj -> saveImage($thumb2, 100);
```

Few examples of images which are not cropped and resized properly :

1)
orginal size : 533x800
resized to : 229x373

2)
orginal size : 567x850
resized to : 229x346

3)
orginal size : 245x398
resized to : 229x373

Is there any option to resize and crop them to exact size ?

Comment: Well, I suggest you start implementing error detection and handling... in software you cannot always blindly assume that all things work fine.  How should _we_ know why your image conversions fail? We don't have your images...

Comment: From the docs for parameter `crop`: _“Will resize the image and then crop the image for the best fit, making the image the exact size you specify”_ – so if it doesn’t do what it has promised, then you should file a bug report.

Comment: @arkascha You don't need images. I proccessed about 3,5k photos and only some of them are resized to different size. I know that must be logic explanation. That's not coincidence.

Comment: Provide a single example of an image _not_ cropped although its dimensions are wider than what you specify as cropping area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this problem, and couldn't find any other questions than this, so i think its worth.

for some reason it doesn't pass this check inside resizeImage function:

```
if (($optimalWidth >= $newWidth && $optimalHeight >= $newHeight)) { 
    $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight, $cropPos);
  }
```

It appears your optimal width is less than new width, its getting 229 (maybe 229.xxxx) as your optimal width and 230 is your new width(which is just your desired width). That's why it resizes but doesn't crop. However it may echo 230 (here its 899 but if i echo it writes 900), dont know why. Using ceil() when getting the values should solve it, just above the IF.

```
$optimalWidth  = ceil($dimensionsArray['optimalWidth']);
$optimalHeight = ceil($dimensionsArray['optimalHeight']);
```

Comment: That fixed this problem. Thanks once more for reply